# mysql_store_result returning null but no error message

Tags: c++, mysql

I have multiple clients all making mysql calls. When I only have one client make a call everything works fine. If I have multiple clients make calls simultaneously the mysql_store_result() functions sometimes returns NULL. The specific query I am testing with is a SELECT query. I am under the impression that when mysql_store_result() returns NULL there is a problem (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-store-result.html,) but mysql_error() returns no string, mysql_errno() returns 0, and mysql_field_count() returns 0 (i.e. it doesn't think the query should have returned anything even though I sent it a SELECT query.)

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What application language are you using? The C API I presume? Please add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Yes, I am using the MYSQL C API.